# Groupby Sum ignoring few columns

Tags: python, pandas

In this DataFrame I would like to groupby 'Location' and get the sum of 'Score' but I wouldn't want 'Lat','Long' & 'Year' to be affected in the process;

```
sample = pd.DataFrame({'Location':['A','B','C','A','B','C'],
                       'Year':[2001,2002,2003,2001,2002,2003],
                       'Lat':[24,32,14,24,32,14],
                       'Long':[81,85,79,81,85,79],
                       'Score':[123,234,10,25,46,11]})

grouped = sample.groupby(['Location']).sum().reset_index()
```

`grouped` gives me this;

```
  Location  Lat   Long   Score   Year
0   A       48     162    148   4002
1   B       64     170    280   4004
2   C       28     158     21   4006
```

But I'm looking for this result;

```
     Location   Lat   Long   Score   Year
    0   A       24     81     148   2001
    1   B       32     85     280   2002
    2   C       12     79      21   2003
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to provide some form of aggregation method for the other columns. But you can use `mean`, `first` or `last` in this case, which would all work.

```
grouped = sample.groupby(['Location']).agg({'Lat': 'first', 
                                            'Long': 'first', 
                                            'Score': 'sum', 
                                            'Year': 'first'}).reset_index()
```

Gives:

```
  Location  Score  Lat  Long  Year
0        A    148   24    81  2001
1        B    280   32    85  2002
2        C     21   14    79  2003
```

Note that you can also provide your own function instead of the build-in functions in Pandas which can be identified with a string.

It messes up the order of columns, if you care about that simply index with:

```
grouped[['Location', 'Lat', 'Long', 'Score', 'Year']]
```